# What cause the error?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. This is my program to sum two 3x3 matrices and i just don't know how to exit from the while loop, it seems that i can only exit from for loop.
please help.
this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    double a[3][3];
    double b[3][3];
    char str[40];
    int step = 1;
    double resultan;
    while (1) {
        for(int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=3; j++) {
                if (step==1) {
                    printf("Enter value of matrix a row %d column %d = ", i, j);
                    scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
                }
                if (step==2) {
                    printf("Enter value of matrix b row %d column %d = ", i, j);
                    scanf("%lf", &b[i][j]);
                }
                if (step==3) {
                    resultan = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
                    printf("Matriks a[%d][%d] + Matriks b[%d][%d] = ", i,j,i,j);
                    printf("%lf + %lf = %lf\n", a[i][j],b[i][j],resultan);
                }
                if (i==3 && j==3) {
                    step++;
                    Sleep(1);
                }       
            }
        }
        if (step==4) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not [tag:c++], are you aware of the difference between [tag:c] and [tag:c++]?

Comment: When you say "error", what do you mean by that? Build errors? Runtime errors or crashes? Unexpected results? Please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include more details.

Comment: its runtime error, crashes when the variable step=4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in [c](/questions/tagged/c) arrays are indexed from `0` to `N - 1`, so just change

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
```

Also, never ignore the return value of `scanf()`, please read [this documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

And finally there is no point in using a `while` loop like that except in very rare situations, the condition is there for a reason. A human reader would have some trouble figuring out when the `while` loop stops, instead of

```
while (1)
```

use

```
while (step < 4)
```

And your code is unecessarily complicated, write a function `fill_array()` and pass to it the array you want to fill and it's size. That way you don't need such a complicated logic.

The body of your loop does too many things, it should do just one if you want your code to be robust and maintainable.

Comment: Many thanks, i just changed the size of a and b arrays to 4x4 and now i can exit from the while loop.